# How to use scatter chart with complex data?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I trying to implement scatter chart by [example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-series.html).

In example we can see creating dimension:

```
runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [+d.Expt, +d.Run]; });
```

Example's data:

```
Expt Run Speed
1    1   850
1    2   740
1    3   900
```

I want to use same chart, but I have my data in next format:

```
[
 {
  "Timestamp":"2016-12-15T17:29:53Z",
  "idgame":"euro",
  "users":{
    "Jo": {
      "energy":200,
      "jump_height":0.5
     },
    "Bob": {
      "energy":220,
      "jump_height":0.35
     }
  }
 },
 {
  "Timestamp":"2016-12-15T17:29:55Z",
  "idgame":"euro",
  "users":{
    "Jo": {
      "energy":120,
      "jump_height":0.15
     },
    "Bob": {
      "energy":240,
      "jump_height":0.75
     }
  }
 }
]
```

I need to build next chart, where x-axis is `timestamp` and y-axis is `jump_height`:

[image]

My data is allready in crossfilter, so I can't change it.
How can I create good dimension with current format?

Comment: What do you mean by "my data is already in crossfilter"? Crossfilter takes an array of objects, so I'm not clear how this data already is in crossfilter.

Comment: I use this type of data on many other charts with one crossfilter and I allready have some logic for creating dimensions for them. If I change my data before adding to crossfilter, I'll need to rewrite dimension and group creating for other charts

Comment: I got confused because the example data is not an array. However, I guess it could be read as one, with each key/value at the top level being read as a row. But crossfilter filters by row, so if you did get the data in, it could only by filtered by `Expt` - you could not brush the scatter plot.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I'm sorry. I edited data format in the post. So I can't build scatter plot with my data? Maybe you know some lifehack with `compositeChart` or something else?

Comment: Okay I think you can do it, but you won't be able to brush the scatter plot, just the other charts. I'm not sure that it'll be easier than just flattening the data but I think it can be done. That's a good point about a composite or series chart, might be the best way to do it.

Comment: The data format is invalid now, think you must mean without the `"1":` etc. i.e. just an array of objects where `Run` maps to `Speed `.

Comment: Yeah that's clearly not your actual data format and not an array, because arrays don't have key/value pairs. Just try pasting it into [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) for example. I don't understand how you are passing this to crossfilter, and no one will be able to test a solution without some valid data. Sorry.

Comment: @Gordon I'm so sorry, now data is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not convinced this is worth the effort, versus biting the bullet and flattening your data and fixing up the other charts. If your data isn't flat you will be fighting crossfilter and dc.js every step of the way.

That said, as usual, it's possible!

We can't use the series chart, because that requires all the data to be present in one group. But since you want to produce multiple symbols from each row of data, an ordinary crossfilter group can't produce the data you need.

Maybe we could use a fake group, but that would be complicated. Instead, let's produce a dimension and group for each user, and then sew them together using a composite chart.

First, we need to parse those timestamps:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Timestamp = new Date(d.Timestamp);
});
```

Next, we'll retrieve a list of all users, by pulling the user keys from each event (timestamp), concatenating them, and then using a d3.set to unique them:

```
// retrieve all users from all events
var users = data.reduce(function(p, event) {
  return p.concat(Object.keys(event.users));
}, []);
users = d3.set(users).values();
```

In the rest of the code, we'll assume there are the same users for each event. It's possible for them to be different, but it adds extra complexity, and this answer is complicated enough. Just ping me me if you need that feature!

We'll create the chart, crossfilter, and a scale which will assign symbols to users:

```
var chart = dc.compositeChart("#test");
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var symbolScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range(d3.svg.symbolTypes);
```

Now we can create the composite chart. (We'll add the scatter subcharts in the next step.)

```
chart
  .width(768)
  .height(480)
  .x(d3.time.scale())
  .xUnits(d3.time.seconds)
  .elasticX(true)
  .elasticY(true)
  .brushOn(false)
  .clipPadding(10)
  .shareTitle(false) // allow default scatter title to work
  .shareColors(true) // but use different colors for subcharts
  .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13)
          .gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70));
```

We set up the X axis with a time scale, with a resolution of seconds. Both axes have elastic. We need to share colors so that each subchart will be assigned its own color. (The legend is perhaps overspecified - I copied this from another example.)

Finally we get to the meat of it. For each user, we'll create a subchart, and we'll tell the composite chart to compose all of them:

```
chart.compose(users.map(function(user) {
  var userDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return [d.Timestamp, d.users[user].jump_height];
  })
  var jumpGroup = userDimension.group();
  console.log(user, jumpGroup.all());
  var scatter = dc.scatterPlot(chart)
    .symbol(symbolScale(user))
    .dimension(userDimension)
    .group(jumpGroup)
    .colorAccessor(function() { return user; })
    .symbolSize(8)
    .highlightedSize(10);
  return scatter;
}))
```

We're creating a new dimension for each chart. This is because the dc.js scatter plot expects the keys to include both X and Y coordinates, and we can only access the Y coordinate (`jump_height`) once we know the user. Once we get past that, the group is simple.

The chart will assign the symbol and color based on the user key. These both work the same; an ordinal scale will assign a new value from the range for each new value it encounters in the domain. The only difference is that we're using the default color scale, whereas we had to specify our own symbol scale.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3m4mv3xf/19/

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect. In your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3m4mv3xf/19/) present some intresting bug, when you load page - you can see crosses and circles as symbols on chart, but after `mouseOver` on some legend - symbols changes to same figure. Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Wow, that's a weird one. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Okay, it was [this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/874). Tracked it down and fixed it in dc.js 2.0.5 / 2.1.8. Since the fiddle points to the latest dc.js, it works now.

Comment: I use [this branch](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/tree/gazal-grouped-bar) of dc.js with version `2.1.0-dev`, because I need grouped charts, so I can't take `2.1.8` =( Or maybe this feature is already in `2.1.8` too?

Comment: Although the feature is really close to release, grouped bars need significant work to merge, so they're not part of any release yet. What you can do is [apply the changes from this commit](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/commit/0750a22efe5baa0461208ab7a770476fc3b38b37) to `src/scatter-plot.js` and build the branch, or directly apply the changes to your copy of dc.js. The fix is just three lines.

Comment: Thank you again, I directly applied the changes to my copy of dc.js. Can you also see another question for my scatterChart based on compositeChart? Also we thinking about flattening our data and fixing up the all other charts =)